# React Native & Firebase Search

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo, searchbar

I am trying to use firebase and perform a search. The trouble I am having is when I type the search text the list data isn't being updated.

Below is the code I have come up with

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({loading: true});

    var merchants = new Array;

    merchantsRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        merchants.push({
          id: child.val().id,
          type:  child.val().type,
          attributes: {
            coming_soon: child.val().attributes.coming_soon,
            featured_image_url: child.val().attributes.featured_image_url,
            has_locations: child.val().attributes.has_locations,
            highlight: child.val().attributes.highlight,
            logo_url: child.val().attributes.logo_url,
            main_image_url: child.val().attributes.main_image_url,
            name: child.val().attributes.name,
            offer_active: child.val().attributes.offer_active,
            offer_cta_title: child.val().attributes.offer_cta_title,
            offer_ends_at: child.val().attributes.offer_ends_at,
            offer_starts_at: child.val().attributes.offer_starts_at,
            offer_teaser: child.val().attributes.offer_teaser,
            offer_terms: child.val().attributes.offer_terms,
            offer_text: child.val().attributes.offer_text,
            offer_url: child.val().attributes.offer_url,
            permalink: child.val().attributes.permalink,
            shop_url: child.val().attributes.shop_url,
          },
          _key: child.key
        })
      })
      this.setState({
        data: merchants,
        loading: false,
      })
      // console.log(this.state.data)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error fetching retailer data:', error)
    })

  }

  searchFilterFunction = text => {

    merchantsRef.orderByChild('name').startAt(text.toString()).on('value', function(child) {
        console.log(child.val());
    });

  };

  _renderEmpty = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    )
  }

  _renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <MerchantRow data={item} />
  )

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item._key;

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      console.log("Loading")
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <ActivityIndicator
            animating
            size="large"
          />
          <Text>Fetching shops...</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SearchBar
          placeholder='Search for retailers...'
          containerStyle={{backgroundColor: Colors.blue, borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0}}
          inputStyle={{backgroundColor: Colors.snow}}
          onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
            initialNumToRender={9}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this._renderSeparator}
            removeClippedSubviews={false}
            ListEmptyComponent={this._renderEmpty}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: What does your `SearchBar` component look like?

Comment: @TomDavies its in the code above `<SearchBar
          placeholder='Search for retailers...'
          containerStyle={{backgroundColor: Colors.blue, borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0}}
          inputStyle={{backgroundColor: Colors.snow}}
          onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}
          autoCorrect={false}
        />`

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane, I can't seem to see where you're setting the data on your `searchFilterFunction`, is the function currently console.logging the values correctly? If so, it might just be a matter of needing to run `this.setState({ data: child.val() });

Comment: @ArielSalem when do that I get setstate is undefined

Answer (score 0):

@Paul'Whippet'McGuane, good to know. That's likely because the context of `this` isn't defined. In order to maintain the context of the keyword this, you can modify the searchFilterFunction like so:

```
 searchFilterFunction = text => {
    const that = this;
    merchantsRef.orderByChild('name').startAt(text.toString()).on('value', function(child) {
        console.log(child.val());
        const val = child.val();
        that.setState({ data: val });
    });
  };
```

Comment: @TomDavies, they do, and changing the existing function call from `function(child)  { ....` to `(child) => { ... ` could be a worthy option to look into

Comment: that is presenting a new error 'Invariant Violation tried to get frame out of range' which appears to because flatlist is expecting an array?

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane, what is being console.logged in the searchFilterFunction `child.val()`?

Comment: https://nopaste.xyz/?096907cc94ea6ad7#EjDbvba6osoojT8fhjv7q2XEv/6sAfoxIExfk099pPo=

Comment: Perfect. So the error was telling you that the data that was being set wasn't the correct type (i.e. expected an array, got an object). In your component did mount, you are creating an array of objects based on the child.val(). I'd recommend you utilize that same logic to set the state of your data since it appears that that is what you need to do